# Send image to server from gallery android bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, compression, base64, android-gallery

I tried to send an image to server from gallery, I compressed it with `Base64`.
I started an activity for gallery:

```
private void startGalleryActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    String selectPicture = getResources().getString(R.string.select_picture);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY);
}
```

I received the result in `onActivityResult`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == GALLERY && resultCode == MainActivity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();

        // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
        String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));

        // Now we need to set the GUI ImageView data with data read from the picked file.
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;


        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();

        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Server s = new Server("new");
        s.send(encoded);

        // At the end remember to close the cursor or you will end with the RuntimeException!
        cursor.close();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

When I send the image to serve the size of it is 4 times higher. If I write the image after I read it, this is write with double size. Why do I have this overhead?

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I have this overhead?

In addition to the Base64 overhead itself, you are re-encoding the image as a PNG. If the image started as something else, like a JPEG, a PNG version of that image may be substantially larger.

Also, please delete the four lines preceded by `// Let's read picked image path using content resolver`. First, that code will fail on hundreds of millions of Android devices, because [a `Uri` is not a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html), and you cannot assume that you can get a local filesystem path for that data. Second, you do not need it, as `BitmapFactory` has a `decodeStream()` method that you can use with `getContentResolver().openInputStream(pickedImage)`.

In addition, please do not call `decode...()` on `BitmapFactory` twice. Load the bitmap once. Use the bitmap both for the `ImageView` and for your uploading.

Answer (score 1):

Calling compress on a PNG will not make your file smaller as it is already compressed. Converting a binary file to a text stream
will really make it big.  To avoid less overhead by converting the PNG file
to text file, just send the file as is, as a byte array. And add the file length
in the header. You can use DataOutputStream to do this.

```
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();

ByteArrayOutputStream btOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dataOS = new DataOutputStreamEx(btOS);

dataOS.writeInt(byteArray.length); // length of file
dataOS.write(byteArray);           // actual file
dataOS.write(0);                   // end of field
dataOS.close()
```

I don't know what you are using in the backend, but you can just read
the first 4 bytes of what you will receive and that will be the length
of you file. And use that length to read the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

It will be approximately 37% larger:

> Very roughly, the final size of Base64-encoded binary data is equal to
>   1.37 times the original data size

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 0):

You are using Bitmap and BitmapFactory to convert a small jpg file to a big png file. Why aren't you sending the jpg directly? So do NOT use Bitmap and BitmapFactory to begin with. You end up else with something that was not your file.